# Не получается распарсить html страницу

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup, parse

Есть у меня страница в гугле - https://www.google.com/search?q=rick+owens+ramones, и мне ее нужно для примера распарсить, чтобы потом было понятно как парсить похожие, только с другим параметром q. Однако, код не работает, просто возвращает None.

```
def get_product(url):
  import requests, bs4
  r = requests.get(url)
  BS = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
  return BS.find('div', {"class": "mnr-c"})


print(get_product("https://www.google.com/search?q=rick+owens+ramones"))
```

[image: данные, которые необходимо спарсить]

Comment: на этой странице нет ни 1 `div` с `"class":"mnr-c"` что вам надо парсить с этой страницы?

Comment: А что вы хотите с страницы вытащить? У меня нашлось, но не в классе, а `data-slct="mnr-c"`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin мне необходимо спарсить несколько рекламных блоков

Comment: @gil9red мне нужно несколько рекламных блоков вытащить

Comment: каких? Добавьте конкретики. Хотя бы скрин того что вы хотите спарсить.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin добавил скрин в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое, это реклама и она будет показывать всегда разное.
Второе если возвращает `None` то вполне возможно реклама просто не появилась.

Comment: Если же вам интересно как всё таки достать текст, то скажу. Надо приостановить процесс после запрося для того чтобы js прогрузил всю рекламу)